# Grafana worldmap didn't work with Elasticsearch geo_point field

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I would like use Grafana worldmap to show (aggregated) points which are stored in elasticsearch in geo_point field type. But it failed. Grafana reported "Error: Missing geohash value"

[image]

The above image shown that I've add a document with field "location", and the field is mapping to geo_point type. I can see the point in Kibana map without any problem.

But in Grafana, it reported "Error: Missing geohash value"

These two images below shown my grafana can query and hit to the document. 
[image] 
[image]

And here is the screenshot of my grafana worldmap setting.
Anything I was missing??
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I thought your location field looks like JSON format...

I had same problem with you and I solved my problem changing location data like below picture

[image: location example]

location field make pair of [ lon, lat ]

And I shared my grafana world map pannel settings

Queries

- Query: None
- Metric: Count
- Group by: 'Geo Hash Grid', 'location', [what ever you want value of precision]

Visualization

- Location Data: geohash
- Location Name Field: location
- geo_point/geogash Field: location
- Metric Field: Count

If you succeed display world map data, it labeled geohash value.

Additionally I cannot find a way geohash value to country name.

Comment: This one is grouping the locations by geo hash grid. Is there a way to get every plots of co-ordinates that are in index? also, this is giving grouped count by hash. did you find any way to get the country name?